# mongodb: is find_one_and_update atomic?

Tags: mongodb

I want to specifialy ask about find_one_and_update when using `return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER`

As far as i understand, this action is a combination of 3:

1. search document
2. update document
3. return updated document

I know the search and update parts are atomic. but is the "return" part also atomic?

will the returned document at 3, be only affected by the update process at stage 2? or is it possible ill get a document that was also updated by other threads?

Comment: "_I know the search and update parts are atomic_" - are they?

Answer (score 0):

> I know the search and update parts are atomic. but is the "return" part also atomic?

No.

Once the document is updated the "write lock" on it is released, the value that is returned is a snapshot of the document at that time. Because of network required is takes more than 0 seconds for you to receive the document to your application, and it will take more than 0 seconds for you to preform any action on it in memory.

At the point of the "write lock" release another update could already be queue'd to change the document - this means you can not be sure there hasn't been any more changes to it by the time you receive it.

---

What I like to do in order to deal with this is add a "manual" lock, for example you can add a boolean field `lock` to the document and only release it once your done your processing.

Just make sure to "unlock it"

```
// the "`lock: {$ne: true}` should be part of all queries you want blocked throughout your app.
const doc = await db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ ...query, lock: {$ne: true} }, { $set: {...updateBody, lock: true })

if (doc) {
  // do whatever, this document is safe.
} else {
  // doc is either "locked" or does not exist, need to deal how you want.
}

await db.collection.updateOne(query, { $set: { lock: false } })
```

Obviously this toy approach is risky as if your process errors and or is killed without unlocking this document will forever remain locked.

What I actually do is use a timestamp to deal with this, meaning I lock the document for X seconds - this allows me to know the document is safe for my processing (X configurable for my needs ) and that I don't need to bother unlocking it.

```
// this will lock documents for 1 second.
const start = new Date();
const doc = await db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ ...query, lock: {$gt: new Date(start + 1000 )}, { $set: {...updateBody, lock: start })

if (doc) {
  // safe for processing for 1 second.
  ...
  // if (start.getTime() + 1000 > new Date().getTime()) no longer safe
} else {
  // doc is locked or does not exist
}

// optional, can unlock if finished early.
await db.collection.updateOne(query, {$unset: {locked: ""}})
```

Comment: "Once the document is updated the "write lock" on it is released, the value that is returned is a snapshot of the document at that time." - that is "atomic" in my book.

Comment: Yes, the update by definition is atomic, but OP is referring the "post update" timeframe.

Comment: by your answer it also sounds atomic to me. if the returned document is the snapshot of the document after the given update, it sounds atomic (no other changes were made on that document)

Comment: I think I understood our miss understanding.
So yes the "result" return is atomic in the sense that it is the document after the specific update and no "other" updates will change that result.

it is -not- atomic in the sense that the document can be changed by an additional update by the time you process it into memory- which is what i thought you meant.